# How do I disable the colored highlighting left of the line numbers in the Bracket Editor? What is it called/for?

Tags: adobe-brackets

See below for a screenshot of my brackets editor in a css file.
I see the colored highlighting for all file types. I am not sure what to call it. 
I have been downloading extensions lately so it could be one of them but not sure what its called and thus can't search online for how to disable it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those colored marks are the "gutter marks" from the [Brackets Git](https://github.com/brackets-userland/brackets-git) extension. They indicate added (green), modified (yellow/orange), or deleted (red) lines in the current file.

Personally, I find them very helpful. In case you still want to turn them off, go to the Git Settings and check the box for "Use Git gutter marks".
[image: Brackets Git Settings: Git gutter marks]